# Return object - python inline if

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm tring to write the one line equivalent to:

```
if userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache:
            return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]
```

So, i tried:

```
return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet] if userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache else None
```

But this line returns `Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]` or `None` depnding on the evaluation of the expression.

The following gives me an error:

```
None if not userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache else return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]
```

Is there a way to selective return a value using inline if, and if not I would appreciate an explanation as to why.

Comment: What is it supposed to do if the userSet isn't in it? why does this have to be on one line?

Comment: If it's not in it, nothing supposes to happen. I prefer using inline ifs as the code is shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a 1 line-code? Why?

If it's about style and performance then start by doing only one lookup in `Cluster.salientGroupCache`:

```
try:
    return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]
except KeyError:  # or another error (it's a dict, right?)
    pass
```

That's probably faster and more pythonic because it follows the [EAFP principle: "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission."](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)

---

About your exception:

```
None if not userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache else return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]
#              that's not allowed in an expression----^^^^^^
```

However the:

```
return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet] if userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache else None
```

should work without problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your first code on one line if you want:

```
if userSet in Cluster.salientGroupCache: return Cluster.salientGroupCache[userSet]
```

This is not great style, but it does exactly what you want. You can't use an `if` expression for this because `return` is a statement, and you can't nest a statement inside an expression.

Answer (score 0):

> If it's not in it, nothing supposes to happen.

Then what you are doing won't work, when using the `return` keyword, something gets returned. So just keep it as you originally had it so code can continue to flow if the `userSet` isn't in the group

> I prefer using inline ifs as the code is shorter.

This is a very dangerous way to start learning to code.

Yes, you may sometimes look smarter to others but the second they start to realise that your "one-liner" is actually making performance slower, they will be just reverting your code back to the simpler form.